# Can I compress a bitmap from one end but leave the other end intact

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

I have a Bitmap that is rectangular and I want to slowly reduce the size of one end of the Bitmap and sample the pixels accordingly while leaving the other end intact. The Bitmap will become a trapezium and eventually a triangle.
Can anybody help me achieve this in android?

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little further? It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This question seems perfectly self-evident: OP wants to animate a bitmap from its original rectangular shape into a triangle, formed by gradually reducing the height of one side from its original size down to zero. Here is a visual example of what OP is trying to achieve in Android: http://imgur.com/EUFhKax

Comment: Thanks MusiGenesis... That is exactly what I want to achieve. Can someone please help...?